# How do I write pure functional code if my values need to be updated based on the previous value?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

From my understanding of FRP, we should use pure functions which means that the input is not mutated. How do I create a pure function which relies on the previous value?

For example, I have an object which moves horizontally every time I press the space key. This means that the x value needs to be updated based on the previous x value.

Initially, object starts at x -> 0. Pressed space key, x -> 1. Pressed space key again, x -> 2.

If we are not allowed to mutate the value of x like this (javascript code),

```
let x = 0;
function set_x() {
    x += 1;
  }
```

how can my program remember what the previous value of x is?

Comment: Either pass in the previous x each time, or don't bother trying to be functional here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181684/how-to-implement-settable-and-retrievable-state-without-mutation-nor-reassignmen

Comment: @Snow how do we pass in the previous x without reassigning the variable (aka mutating it)

Comment: Use a different variable, or (as in the link) don't bother trying to be functional

Comment: functions are made to take arguments. If we're going to become so pedantic that calling a function multiple times is considered mutation and must be avoided I'm finally looking for those architect roles

Comment: @GeorgeJempty The "functional" issue here is not that the function is called multiple times, but that OP essentially wants it to have state, which is impure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally FRP works by creating one stream from another using higher-order functions. When you need the previous value of the stream, the function you want is going to be called `fold`, `reduce` or `scan`. It takes an event stream, a starting value and function and produces another stream that starts with the starting value and then takes the result of `f(p, x)` (where `p` is the previous value of the new stream and `x` the current value of the original stream) every time there's an event on the original stream.

For example, in Bacon.JS the method you want is called `scan` (`fold` also exists, but only emits the final value, so doesn't do what we want here) and your code could look like this:

```
const numberOfSpacePresses = spacePressEvents.scan(0, (count, _) => count + 1);
```

Some libraries may also already have a function or method named `count` that does what you want, so you could just write `spacePressEvents.count()`.